String concatenation too long error in Oracle
I have two columns A and B. A is like a sequence(1,2,3,4) and B(b1,b2,b3,b4) is data related to each sequence. I have one more column lets say Z for each Z column(zxxxxxx) .
Data present in this format in table



 
 




zxxxxxx
1:b1


zxxxxxx
2:b2


zxxxxxx
3:b3


zxxxxxx
4:b4



I want output like this  for column z:
zxxxxxx
1:b1 
2:b2
3:b3
4:b4

In addition to above :If I remove column A its working but if I concatenate with B it throws error.
I wrote the below query but getting error String concatenation too long
SELECT 
RTRIM((Xmlagg(Xmlelement(e,(A||':'||B)||',')).extract('//text().getclobval(),','||
chr(10)|| '')
from table_name where decision in ('X','Y')
 and Z='zxxxxxx';


column A is number type and Column B is NVARCHAR

Have you tried LISTAGG?

Listagg have limitation of 2000 char only. And Column B has data more than 2k characters

I'd consider doing the concatenation in an above layer.

Could you please provide sample how to do concatenation in an above layer.

You appear to want to use GROUP BY a and only aggregate the B column and then concatenate:
SELECT EMPTY_CLOB()
       || a
       || CHR(10)
       || RTRIM(Xmlagg(Xmlelement(e, B||CHR(10))).extract('//text()').getclobval(), CHR(10))
           AS output
from   table_name
WHERE  decision in ('X','Y')
AND    Z='zxxxxxx'
GROUP BY a;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (a, b, decision, z) AS
SELECT 'zxxxxxx', '1:b1', 'X', 'zxxxxxx' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'zxxxxxx', '2:b2', 'Y', 'zxxxxxx' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'zxxxxxx', '3:b3', 'X', 'zxxxxxx' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'zxxxxxx', '4:b4', 'X', 'zxxxxxx' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'aaaaaaa', RPAD('1', 2000, '1'), 'X', 'zxxxxxx' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'aaaaaaa', RPAD('2', 2000, '2'), 'X', 'zxxxxxx' FROM DUAL

Outputs:



OUTPUT




aaaaaaa1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111122222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222


zxxxxxx1:b14:b43:b32:b2



fiddle

The formatting in the question is confusing. If your sample data is actually something like:
CREATE TABLE table_name (z, a, b, decision) AS
SELECT 'zxxxxxx', 1, 'b1', 'X' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'zxxxxxx', 2, 'b2', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'zxxxxxx', 3, 'b3', 'X' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'zxxxxxx', 4, 'b4', 'X' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'aaaaaaa', 1, RPAD('1', 2000, '1'), 'X' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'aaaaaaa', 2, RPAD('2', 2000, '2'), 'X' FROM DUAL

Then use:
SELECT EMPTY_CLOB()
       || z
       || CHR(10)
       || RTRIM(
            Xmlagg(
              Xmlelement(
                e,
                EMPTY_CLOB()||A||':'||B||CHR(10)
              )
            ).extract('//text()').getclobval(),
            CHR(10)
          ) AS output
from   table_name
WHERE  decision in ('X','Y')
GROUP BY z;

fiddle
